# game loop inconsistency between firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript

https://i.stack.imgur.com/75YGB.jpg

This is an animated GIF that I took for the demonstration.
Only 320 lines of codes are used and the structure is simple.

The problem is, when I open it in Firefox it stutters severely.
In chrome, it works just fine.
I wonder why this is happening.

At first I thought it has something to do with my codes.
Because there were many local variables inside each functions.
So I eliminated them and now it works fine in Chrome.
But it still happens in Firefox.
I do not know how to interpret devTools' performance profile.

```
Obj Input      // contains vars, funcs,
Obj Game       // contains vars, funcs,
Obj Graphic    // contains vars, funcs,

var RAF = requestAnimationFrame;
func main(){
    //lastTime, now, delta for calculating x, y values
    ...
    Input.update(delta);
    Game.process(delta);
    Graphic.draw();
    ...
    RAF(main);
}
main();
```

This is simplified version of my code.

I've searched how to control FPS using RAF, how to use devTools but, I'm simply clueless about this behavior. Anyone can enlighten me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR7Q0.jpg Images of firefox/chrome profile.

UPDATE:

I've tested it on firefox, firefox devEdition, chrome. Only the firefox in the extended monitor happens to cause this problem. I've even reduce the size of the canvas and confirmed that this has nothing to do with browsers' performance nor the code optimization.

My guess is that, when the firefox browser moves to one monitor from another, it tries to re-adjust how to process it-rAF, re-drawing, etc. And while doing so, firefox cannot properly process it in my extended monitor.

This is indeed very interesting and I'd like to delve deeper. But it is clear enough for me to conclude it.

Comment: what about getting time at beginning of `main()` and at the end of it and make the difference? if you're tanking more than `1000 / screenFrameRate` ms it's a performance problem (do it just for testing purposes)

Comment: @FeMachine You gave me a strange idea and it led me to an unexpected result. I'm currently using a laptop and another monitor for extended screen. I've been testing in this extended screen. When I moved the firefox window to laptop screen, it worked great. Then I move it back, it stutters again. Chrome doesn't do this. I'm even more puzzled now.

Comment: maybe firefox can't detect your monitor's framerate and refreshes 30 times per second instead of 60 :D

Comment: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/Frame_rate) there's a explanation on how it works, maybe you can try the frame rate tool to investigate a little bit

Comment: @FeMachine Thank you. It starts to make a sense somehow. I'll look for related topics. Appreciate for your help. :)